# BerkeleyDB: exclusive lock for a whole database

Tags: c++, database, locking, berkeley-db

Is there some way to acquire an exclusive write lock for a whole Berkeley DB database without having to close it and reopen it using [Db::set_lk_exclusive()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/CXX/dbset_lk_exclusive.html)?

Perhaps using [DbEnv::lock_get()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/CXX/lockget.html)? But in this case, how should it be called? I haven't found any examples about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same [question in the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10736705#10736705) and got a reply:

> There is no way to get an exclusive write lock on a BDB database if you have already opened it to use page level locking. DbEnv::lock_get(), and the rest of the lock interface, should really only be used if you plan to manage all locks obtained in the environment.